# Read with ImageIO non-applet

Tags: java, javax.imageio

Okay, so I have all of my classes inside of a few packages:
Game/src/package1/Class.class

and I want to get into a file in:
Game/res/Terrain.png

How would I do this?

```
public Screen(Game game){
    this.game=game;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("/res/Terrain.png");
        textures = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

then i get this error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /res/Terrain.png
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:583)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:480)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:429)
    at kore.survival.Screen.<init>(Screen.java:25)
    at kore.survival.Game.<init>(Game.java:27)
    at kore.survival.Game.main1(Game.java:99)
    at kore.survival.LoginFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(LoginFrame.java:201)
    at kore.survival.LoginFrame.access$200(LoginFrame.java:16)
    at kore.survival.LoginFrame$3.actionPerformed(LoginFrame.java:82)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the resource is embedded with the Jar...

```
textures = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/Terrain.png"));
```

Comment: @MouseEvent Now you're just ruining my fun ;)